# Structure of "if" and "else"

Tags: function, swift, validation, if-statement

I'm a beginner with Swift and had a quick question about the structure of "if" and "else". I am following a tutorial about validating usernames and passwords.

This is the current code I have:

```
let username = "brian0306"
let password = "secret"

if (username == "brian0306") {
    println("")
    if (password == "secret") {
        println("❤️")
    } else {
        println("Uh oh, your credentials are wrong!")
    }
} else {
        println("Uh oh, your username is wrong!")
}
```

Why is the tutorial suggesting that I place the password validation code within the username validation function?

Is it more effective if I validate the username and password in separate functions?

Comment: no because you check username first and if it matches then you check password as you have hard coded values in there the way you are doing it is the best approach. You are only validating against 1 user and you know if there username does not match there no point checking the password. Therefore you check the username and then conform the password.

Comment: @JoshStevens There is no real difference as if you try to validate username and password as soon as the first validation fail the second does not take place.

Comment: what? @IcaroNZ i was explaining how he did it is perfectly fine and why the website talking him through it would tell him to code it that way

Comment: @bmoondesign The pos of this approach is that you know what fail, the user name or the password, the downside is that it makes harder to read the code

Comment: @JoshStevens sorry I may misunderstood what you was saying. I am just pointing that there is no computational benefits between the approaches so the answer should be neither it is not more effective or less effective for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `username` doesn't match then there's not much point checking whether `password` matches, so that's a perfectly good way to do it. You could shorten it to:

```
if username == "brian0306" && password == "secret" {
    println("❤️")
} else {
    println("Uh oh, your username or password is wrong!")
}
```

However that isn't going to tell you which field was incorrect (`username` and/or `password`).